# JavaFX: How to center a TilePane but place the TilePane children from left-to-right?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Like what the title suggest, I'm trying to center a `TilePane` in its parent container, but at the same time, I want the child nodes of the `TilePane` to be placed from left-to-right.

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final VBox root = new VBox();
    final Scene sc = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    
    final TilePane tp = new TilePane();
    root.getChildren().add(tp);
    
    tp.setPrefColumns(3);
    tp.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    tp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setFillWidth(true);

    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(5).forEach(i -> {
        Region r = new Region();
        r.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        r.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 1;");

        tp.getChildren().add(r);
    });

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This creates a window like this:

[image: On launch]

Increasing window width causes this:

[image: Increased width]

Continuing to increase window height causes this:

[image: Increased height]

Setting `root.setFillWidth(false)` causes:

[image: Fill width = false]

What can I do to make sure that the whole `TilePane` remains centered while the `Region` child nodes continues to be placed from left on each row?

#### Update

To make it more clear, the `TilePane` should, during a resize, tries to fit in as many tiles (regions in this example) in all rows except the top row. In other words, there should not be any green space at the right side of the first row. Alternatively, the green space should be equal at both the left and right side. Additionally, the tiles must be placed from left to right. Setting `TilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)` would place any "leftover" tiles at the center of the last row, which is not acceptable.

Comment: hmm .. this is exactly the behaviour as specified. Not sure I understand what you want: on resize, it should remain centered until the next tile fits, then rearrange the tiles such that the green at the right of the first row is never shown? If, my guess is that you would need to implement an custom TilePane..

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, that is what I need. I should not see green space on the first row. I was hoping there is a workaround that doesn't require me to write a custom control.

Comment: nitpicking: not a custom control, but a custom pane, that is basically customize the layout ;) Wondering why do you use a VBox as parent?

Comment: @kleopatra Well, I have tried a few different `Pane` implementations. They generally give the same result. I just need a pane that can center its child.

Comment: in your shoes, I would look into the implementation of TilePane - tweaking computePrefXX and layoutChildren might be enough (though never did for a layout, only for skins)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I'll see if anyone here managed to figure out some hidden tricks before I dive in into subclassing `TilePane`.

Comment: if you are prepared for a bit of c&p: implement a custom TilePane, copy core's layoutChildren (plus all the utility methods) and change the value of the local var _lastRowRemainder_ to be unconditionally 0. Doing so will center the tilePane as needed and layout the last row at the same x offset as the rows above.

Comment: @kleopatra Hmm, there are a couple of private fields :(

Comment: not really - actualRows/columns are used only inside the layout code (don't know why they are fields at all?) and everything else private is plain utility code afaics, no guarantee ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the preferred size of the tiles via `TilePane`. Prevent the parent from resizing the `TilePane` beyond it's prefered size by setting `fillWidth` to `false` and use a listener to the `width` property of the `VBox` to set the `prefColumns` property:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final VBox root = new VBox();
    final Scene sc = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);

    final TilePane tp = new TilePane();
    tp.setPrefTileWidth(200);
    tp.setPrefTileHeight(200);
    root.getChildren().add(tp);

    tp.setPrefColumns(3);
    tp.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    tp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setFillWidth(false);

    // set prefColumns from a listener instead of a binding
    // to prevent the initial value from being set to 0
    root.widthProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // allow as many columns as fit the parent but keep it in
        // range [1, childCount]
        tp.setPrefColumns(Math.min(tp.getChildren().size(),
                Math.max(1, (int) (newValue.doubleValue() / tp.getPrefTileWidth()))));
    });

    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(5).forEach(i -> {
        Region r = new Region();
        r.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 1;");

        tp.getChildren().add(r);
    });

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### Update by OP

I was amazed by this approach, and I tried something slightly more dynamic.

```
root.widthProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    double maxWidth = tp.getChildren()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(n -> n instanceof Region)
                        .map(n -> ((Region) n).getWidth())
                        .max(Double::compareTo)
                        .orElse(0d);

    tp.setPrefColumns(Math.min(tp.getChildren().size(),
            Math.max(1, (int) (newValue.doubleValue() / maxWidth))));
});

Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(5).forEach(i -> {
    Region r = new Region();
    Random random = new Random();
    r.setPrefSize(random.nextInt(150) + 50, random.nextInt(150) + 50);
    System.out.println(r.getPrefWidth());
    System.out.println(r.getPrefHeight());
    r.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 1;");

    tp.getChildren().add(r);
});
```

This removes the need to set a static width/height for each tile.

While this works in this basic example, I have yet tried this on more complex tile children.

Comment: binding wizard :) the "jumping" feels a bit enervating, though - from a UX perspective I would prefer that centered layout with margins left and right

Comment: I tested it and it worked, but my brain hasn't managed to capture how it works. I need some time to digest this magic xD